# Type conversion from DAO to controller

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am stuck in the below issue. I tried to trace out but couldn't. 
Can you guys please do me a favour to solve this issue.

In my controller :

```
Long id = '1425652';
Collection<Long> propIds =  externalTaxManager.getPropertyIdsByTaxId(id); // I have an issue here
Map<Long, Long> propIdToOnegIdMap = externalTaxManager.mapPropertiesToOnegIds(propIds);
```

In my DaoImpl :

```
public Collection<Long> getPropertyIdsByTaxId(Long externalTaxId){
        SQLQuery query = currentSession().createSQLQuery("select b.OMH_PROPERTY_ID from OMH.OMH_EXTERNAL_TAX a , OMH.OMH_EXTERNAL_TAX_PROP_XREF b\n" +
                "where a.OMH_EXTERNAL_TAX_ID=b.OMH_EXTERNAL_TAX_ID and a.OMH_EXTERNAL_TAX_ID= :externalTaxId ");
        query.setParameter("externalTaxId", externalTaxId);
        List<Long> result = query.list();
        return result;
}
```

Here, b.OMH_PROPERTY_ID is long type. There are more than 1000 records in DB for each externalTaxId we pass.

But there is a type mismatch when I am returning from DAO to Controller. I need propIds Collection< Long> only.

Error stacktrace :

```
/ExternalTaxManagerImpl.java:421: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getPropertyIdsByTaxId(java.lang.Long)
location: interface com.orbitz.omh.property.das.svc.ExternalTaxDataService
        return externalTaxDataService.getPropertyIdsByTaxId(externalTaxId);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the error, any stacktrace?

Comment: /ExternalTaxManagerImpl.java:421: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getPropertyIdsByTaxId(java.lang.Long)
location: interface com.orbitz.omh.property.das.svc.ExternalTaxDataService
        return externalTaxDataService.getPropertyIdsByTaxId(externalTaxId);

Comment: please update stacktrace by editing your question. That would be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Long id = '1425652'; This is Invalid character constant
```

change the above declaration as below

```
Long id = 1425652l;
```

**Note :** make sure you keep the 'l' at the end of the number to identify it as a Long  datatype.